# Is aliasing possible in C# anonymous type members?

Tags: c#, ms-project

I am developing a tool to automate some tasks on MSProject using .NET and the `Office.MSProject.Interop` library.

Suppose I have something like that:

```
Project actvProject;
var taskInfoDic = actvProject.Tasks.Cast<Task>().Select(
            task => new
            {
                task.Guid,
                task.Name,
                task.Work,
                task.ActualWork,
                task.PercentWorkComplete,
                task.Start,
                task.Finish,
                task.Duration,
                task.Deadline
            }).ToDictionary(x => x.Guid);

 // More code that mutates actvProject and its Task members
```

Is it possible for the `taskInfoDic` values (which are made of members of a member of the `actvProject` object) to be changed if I mutate `actvProject` ?

Shouldn't an anonymous type value be immutable ??

Comment: Anonymous type members are readonly. Why don't you just promote that to a proper class? That will give you whatever control you want over it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mutate the *dictionary*, as dictionaries are mutable.  This means you can add an entirely new key/value pair, or change the value associated with a key.  You can't mutate the existing value object that some key points to (in this case, because the dictionaries value is an immutable type).

You are also copying all of the data out of the original data source when creating the dictionary, you are not copying references to any of the values, or deferring execution in any way, so there are no changes that could be made to the source data structure that could be observed in the new dictionary.

> Shouldn't a anonymous type value be immutable?

They are.  That doesn't mean that any data structure you put them in is also immutable though.

You could use an `IReadOnlyDictionary` if you want to ensure the dictionary isn't mutated, but given the fact that you're using an anonymous type, you *shouldn't* be using this dictionary outside of the scope of the current method; given that, you really shouldn't need to go to such lengths to prevent mutation of the dictionary, as you are the only one who should be able to mutate it.

Comment: My concern is that the "tasks" (in the activProject object) properties are changed when I work on activProject. I'm concerned if those changes in the activProject are able to reflect themselves into the values of the dictionary. The activProject is a big-gigantic COM object, and there is a ton of side effects when I do my work over it.

To my understanding now, I can't change the reference value inside the anonymous object. But if the referenced object changes it's state, can this change reflect in the values returned by the dictionary??

Comment: @RenanRanelli As I stated in my second paragraph, no changes to the source data structure or its items will be able to be observed in the dictionary you've created, or its items.  That is, unless the properties of `task` that you've pulled out are mutable reference types.  If they are, you'll need to do a deeper copy of them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the `taskInfoDic` values (which are made of members of a member of the `actvProject` object) to be changed if I mutate `actvProject` ?

No, because all of the members you pull out are *value types*.  If any had been *reference types* than all you have is a reference, and changes to the underlying instances would be reflected in the results of your query.

> Shouldn't a anonymous type value be immutable ??

Yes they should, and they *are*.  However, you are creating a *dictionary* where the anonymous type is the *value*.  Dictionaries are mutable, but the values (in this case) are not.

Comment: I thought anonymous types are reference types, not value types.

Comment: @Servy I was referring to the fields pulled out of the original `task` list - `Guid`, `Name`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough example that shows once you populate an anonymous type, it's data cannot be changed implicitly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var actvProject = new Project();

        var taskInfoDic = actvProject.Tasks.Cast<Task>().Select(
        task => new
        {
            task.Guid,
            task.Name
        }).ToDictionary(x => x.Guid);

        actvProject.Tasks[0].Name = "New Task";

        foreach (var t in taskInfoDic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Value.Name);    // Still "Task 1"
        }

        // This won't compile as "Name" is readonly.
        // taskInfoDic.ElementAt(0).Value.Name = "test";
    }
}

public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task> { new Task { Name = "Task 1" } };
    }

    public IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```